# Angular subscribe to @Input object change

Tags: angular, subscribe

I have an object in my parent component that looks like this and is passed down to my child component (app-custom-component):

```
myObject = {
  name: 'John'
}
...
<app-custom-component [inputObject]="myObject"></app-custom-component>
```

And in my child component (app-custom-component) I do this:

```
@Input() inputObject;
displayName = '';

ngOnInit() {
  this.displayName = this.inputObject.name;
}
...
<label>{{displayName}}</label>
```

But when I change the `myObject.name` in the parent component it doesn't update the child component's `displayName`.

**How can I make `displayName` update when I change `myObject.name` in the parent component?**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqiorv

Comment: It works just fine, open your console for errors.

Answer (score 5):

It would be pretty easier with `getter` for `displayName`.

```
@Input() inputObject;

ngOnInit() {

}

get displayName(){
   return this.inputObject.name;
}
```

...

```
<label>{{displayName}}</label>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Would you mind explaining how this works or referencing docs please? :)

Comment: Getter will be called whenever Angular goes throgh Change Detection Process which ensure that latest changes are being reflected in the html template.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use getter and setter methods for inputs

```
@Input() 
get inputObject()  {
    return this.displayName;
}
set inputObject(value) {
     this.displayName = this.inputObject.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, onInit() only gets executed once, when the component is initialized. Try putting your code in the ngOnChanges() as well.

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.displayName = this.inputObject.name;
}
```

Comment: He coould simply create a getter for display name istead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngOnChange()` and track all changes of related `@Input`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to avoid getter for this, so you don't have unnecessary re-rendering.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  this.displayName = changes.inputObject.currentValue.name;
}
```

Make sure to implement `OnChanges` interface too.